# Symfony Can't persist olders information

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have an entity with some 2 checkbox. So, the first time my entity appears with checkbox checked as it was stored look here:
Screenshot of [Entity as it was stored](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vy45g.png). When I try to change them here before submission (I set checked on 2 checkbox) (by a POST Request) and persist it. Doctrine doesn't save the **OLDER** statement. But persists the new changements. I don't know why.

Here is a screenshot [after submission and refresh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KeSgb.png)

My controller code

```
foreach ($_POST as $item => $value) {

    $champTable = $em->getRepository('IPSEtabsSectBundle:TablePropriete')->find($item);

    if ($value[0] == 'true') {
        $champTable->setRequire('true');
    }

    if ($value[0] == 'obligatoire') {
        $champTable->setAttributes('obligatoire');
        $champTable->setRequire(NULL);
    }
    if (isset($value[1]) && ($value[1] == 'obligatoire')) {
        $champTable->setRequire('true');
        $champTable->setAttributes('obligatoire');
    }
    //var_dump($champTable);
    $em->persist($champTable);
    $em->flush();
}
```

Comment: Pls share full code of Controller function and form type

Comment: Use symfony profiler and look in your POST vars, inspect what values are sending your form.

Comment: My variables exists in my POST. I try with another method (I use a personal DQL function) and It's good. Thank you for help me